# Reading a file that might be truncated in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, truncate

I'm using Perl to read through a log file that might be truncated at any point. If this happens, I want to start reading the file at the beginning again, but the default Perl behaviour seems to be to wait until the file pointer has caught up. For example, if I run the following:

```
perl -e 'open FILE, "test"; while (1) { $line = <FILE>; print "$line"; }'
```

and then do:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i >> test; done
:>test
for i in 4 5 6 7; do echo $i >> test; done
```

the output I get is:

```
1
2
3
7
```

But if I were to do the same thing, replacing the Perl code with:

```
tail -f test
```

then (ignoring tail output to stderr) I get the output I want, i.e.:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Obviously, I can't just use tail because I want to do some processing on the line itself. One thought I did have was combining the two:

```
tail -f test | perl -e 'while (1) { $line = <STDIN>; print "$line"; }'
```

which works on my Linux development machine but unfortunately not on the Solaris target platform.

Any ideas?

As requested, an example of using File::Tail is as follows:

```
perl -e 'use File::Tail; $file = File::Tail->new("test"); while (defined($line=$file->read)) { print "$line"; }'
```

If I then enter data into test as before, the output I get is just:

```
7
```

which is obviously not as desired. I've tried adjusting the maxinterval that File::Tail will wait as follows:

```
perl -e 'use File::Tail; $file = File::Tail->new(name => "test", maxinterval => 1); while (defined($line=$file->read)) { print "$line"; }'
```

but in that case, entering data into the test file too quickly, like so:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i >> test; done; :>test; for i in 4 5 6 7; do echo $i >> test; done
```

results in just:

```
4
5
6
7
```

Unfortunately, that's a realistic scenario for our (very busy) application. For the sake of comparison, Linux tail appears to handle that sort of data entry speed properly, so it's fairly clear that it can be done (although to be fair, maybe not in Perl....?)

Comment: How is that line failing on the Solaris box?

Comment: It's not failing, but tail on Solaris doesn't work the same way as on Linux, and the output I get is 1 2 3 7, not 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. At least, that's the case on our production Solaris installs. Sorry - that could have been clearer in the original question.

Comment: So, short version, you want to implement `tail` in Perl?

Comment: Well, no, because I need to do extra processing on the lines that I'm reading. Specifically, I'm looking for lines matching a particular regex so that I can chop data out of the line for use in an aggregation calculation later on. And as I said before, tail on Solaris doesn't work the way I'd need it to anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Linux `tail` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) uses the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) mechanism to monitor changes to the file without having to repeatedly poll it for updates.  This allows it to respond quickly and reliably to any changes in the file.

To implement similar functionality in Perl, you could use the [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Linux%3a%3aInotify2) module from CPAN.  Unfortunately, as the name indicates, this module only works on Linux, so it won't help you in porting your script to Solaris.

You *might* be able to use [FAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor) with the [SGI::FAM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SGI%3a%3aFAM) module instead; it may still internally fall back to polling if there's no native file change notification mechanism available, but at least it should provide a reasonably good and tested implementation of file polling.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wish to emulate `tail` in Perl.

- If you have access to CPAN, you can use [`File::Tail`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTail).

  It's pure Perl (not XS) so you can see how it's implemented [in the source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MGRABNAR/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm) if no CPAN access.
- Also, see [PerlFAQ5](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-do-a-tail--f-in-perl-) ("How do I do a tail -f in perl?")

Comment: Thanks - I found that after I posted the question, and I've been looking at it, but I'm not sure it's ideally suited to my needs - in initial testing, I was able to make it skip lines it should have read, which didn't leave me with a great feeling.

Comment: @AndyB - could you please post the specific example of the File::Tail failure into the Q?